# How to add statistical question and answers MCQ entry management in statistical exam equation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2017

I am going to setup a exam management system for statistics.

Exam questions and answers contains some equations, formulas and some graphs.

Exam is MCQ type questions and answers

How can I make entry from admin panel?

[Output Sample 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAU2J.png)

[image]

[Output Sample 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq1WV.png)

[image]